# Is drag-and-drop possible in watir-webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I would like to drag-and-drop one element to the position of another, triggered from within a watir-webdriver script.

By "drag-and-drop" I mean picking up a draggable element and releasing it on another. By "possible" I mean any method for drag/drop that can be executed from a watir-webdriver script. This includes code snippets, third party gems, etc.

As I understand it drag-and-drop is a feature request for core watir-webdriver (at time of asking), so I'm looking (in principle) for an alternative.

Comment: This Selenium TipsAndTricks page suggests it is possible to implement drag-and-drop on top of webdriver (Firefox but not IE): http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks.

Comment: The best venue for technical questions regarding Watir or associated gems like watir-webdriver is the main StackOverflow site

Comment: Yeah I do wish QA would migrate to SQA&T. Thanks for the advice, though, I shall do a crosspost of victory.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'm doing drag and drop in watir-webdriver. This only works in Firefox:

browser.div(:text=>"from_div").wd.drag_and_drop_on(browser.div(:text=>"to_div").wd)

Comment: Many thanks. Should be noted for other users that wd is part of the private API so shouldn't be used for large projects that cannot maintain a change to it. Luckily I'll use whatever I can get, and for non-IE testing this may prove very useful

Comment: Still in today, it is working in firefox, but not in chrome! Is there a consistent fix for `drag_and_drop_on/drag_and_drop_by` in chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar using events and/or autoit..  don't recall off the top of my head what the solution was (would need to go back and find that code)

I'd recommend asking on the main StackOverflow site and tag the question with Watir and Watir-webdriver..  a lot more of the Watir folks watch that site than this one